# React Navigation 5 route.params undefined even though I provide a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am currently stuck on a react navigation problem and I have consulted the docs as well and it seems like I am setting it up correctly but I may be missing something. I have a button that is routing to the main screen and am passing a prop

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, Picker } from 'react-native';
// not sure if i need to import navigation? It seems to work since it's a screen

const LevelScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [ gridSize, setGridAmount ] = useState(3);

    return (
             // OTHER CODE THAT SHOULDN'T REALLY HAVE AN EFFECT ON THIS

             <Button
                title='Continue'
                // this should navigate to the mainScreen
                // needs to pass in row and column 
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate(
                  'Game', { gridSizeVal: 3 }
                )}
            />
```

and this is the screen i'm navigating to:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Grid from '../components/Grid';
import ConsoleBox from '../components/ConsoleBox';
import COLORS from '../core/commonText';
// Not sure if i need to import navigation from react/react-native? 

const GameScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const { gridSizeValue } = route.params;
    // The rest of my code
```

but it keeps responding with a `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params')`
I attempted to use both `route.params.gridSizeValue` and `route.params.gridSizeValue.name` but they all resort to the same error. I am currently on `version 5.0.9` for react-navigation/native. I've consulted https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params and it seems like i'm doing everything except I use arrow functions instead of explicit functions and I'm still learning react-native so that might not have any differences? If this is a duplicate question I would gladly go to that question but I can't seem to find anything. Thanks!

EDIT: I ran a `console.log(route)` and it returned `undefined`. I also tried to use `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Game', { gridSizeVal: 3})}` but got a typeError: `Undefined is not an object (evalutating '_this.props.navigation')`.

I also figured the my `App.js` and `index.js` might have something to do with it so this is the `App.js`:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import GameScreen from './src/screens/GameScreen';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LevelScreen from './src/screens/LevelScreen';

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Level: LevelScreen,
    Game: GameScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Level',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'Game Of Seasons'
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

and my `index.js` is:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: Try `console.log(route)` in GameScreen Component and describe that here

Comment: So console logging returns a ```undefined```. I also updated the question so the code is more complete.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So the answer ended up being `navigation.state.params.gridSizeVal` and the code block with it was:

```
const GameScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [ gridSize, setGridSize ] = useState(navigation.state.params.gridSizeVal);
```

One problem I have is that I wasn't able to assign the prop to a value in this example:

```
let { gridSizeValue } = navigation.state.params.gridSizeVal;
```

Console logging the above returned `undefined` but this worked for my problem of getting the params through the navigation stack.

Comment: Regarding why you receive an `undefined` value - you're destructuring a value that shouldnt be destructured. Try `const gridSizeValue = navigation.state.params.gridSizeVal;`

Comment: navigation.state.params looks to me like you are using react navigation 4 no?

Answer (score 4):

You are importing version 4.x of react-navigation but you are following the documentation for 5.x. Destructured `{route}` was not available in 4.x (instead the passed in parameters came from `navigation.state.params`).

See the official documentation for more details: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x

Answer (score 1):

If your stack navigator is the root navigator, then you can easily pass the parameters to the other screen (same level as the current screen) as follows.

```
<Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('nameComponentInStack', {screen: 'ScreenName', params: {paramName: paramValue}})}
```

Comment: thank you, never though about that but solved my case!!

Comment: glad that it solved :)